# LC-3, LDI isn't getting right address?

Tags: lc3

My code below is supposed to simply print a prompt, but it's printing a bunch of y-looking characters instead. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

CODE:

```
startPrompt .STRINGZ "Enter 'E' to encrpyt, 'D' to decrpyt, X to quit\n" 

startPromptAddress .FILL startPrompt 

LDI R0, startPromptAddress

PUTS
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want LEA, not LDI.

LEA Loads a register with the ADDRESS of LABEL (not its contents!). Often used with .STRINGZ and PUTS to print a string.

LDI gets the address that is stored at the LABEL (or an offset), and then gets the VALUE at THAT address (this is the indirect "i" part of LDI).

Here's the full code that should work in a typical LC3 simulator (I used the one at lc3tutor.org to verify:

--------------- cut here ---------------

.ORIG x3000

startPrompt .STRINGZ "Enter 'E' to encrpyt, 'D' to decrpyt, X to quit\n"

LEA R0, startPrompt; load the address at 'startPrompt' into R0

PUTS; print characters starting at R0 and continuing until the null character is reached (automatically part of the memory initialized when you use the .STRINGZ directive).

.END

-------------- cut here ---------------

Hope this helps

Jeff

Comment: yeah that helped, thanks! I didn't understand LDI correctly.